# Conveniently randomize image via button from folder/slide?

Tags: vba, random, import, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

I often spend hours bringing pictures into PowerPoint templates one by one and trying to customize the way a presentation whose behavior is very different.

If there were a way to randomly select an image from all of the images on a different slide or excel file or folder and have them appear based on the probable weight assigned to them, it would be a huge time saver.

I've seen various methods of having a random object appear, and some of them don't even require a macro, but importing the images is always very time consuming. If anyone knows of a better/faster way to link a folder with a group of images or something along these lines to an object that is randomized, please help.

Importantly, showing a random image from a batch group without customizing the way each image is brought in is the hard part. Adding weight helps, but it could be done by duplicating important images repeatedly.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd do this w/o VBA, but with it you could have a button click generate a random number, import the image whose filename matches that number (e.g. 42.jpg) to the current or a new slide and then go to that slide. You'd first want to test the slide for any existing prior image and if found, delete it.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I'm trying to get any kind of specific info I can to get the ball rolling on this script.  For example, if you have any info as to how I can use VBA to import files from a folder in batch, it's probably the most difficult challenge.  If you know a simple, progressive tutorial that leads to RNG in VBA for PowerPoint, I'd definitely watch it and try to answer my own question (if only in part).

Comment: I have some code for batch importing on the PPT FAQ site that I maintain:  Batch Insert a folder full of pictures, one per slide
https://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00352_Batch_Insert_a_folder_full_of_pictures-_one_per_slide.htm

Comment: @SteveRindsberg You can do this via the "photo album" button in PowerPoint.  I have some leads on this project.  Let me come back to this comment later this week to show you what I'm looking at so far.  Your code might be easy for me to rework because it probably uses the COM or MSAPI model, and I know how to reference that fairly efficiently.

Comment: Yes, the code example I pointed to could be adapted to use COM automation fairly easily. Let us know how you get on.